# JQuery namespace/code acting funny

Tags: javascript, jquery

First off, [here is my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7v8Xx/).

I have two click listeners. One on a <kbd>Next</kbd> button and one on a <kbd>Back</kbd> button. The listener on the <kbd>Back</kbd> button works great, but the one on the <kbd>Next</kbd>button does not, despite them being in the same area of code.

The line of code in question is:

```
wizard.goTo($('#wizard-pages span[class="selected"]').next().index());
```

Strangely enough, if I run:

```
$('#wizard-pages span[class="selected"]').next().index();
```

I get the right index value. Also, if I run,

```
wizard.goTo(x);
```

(x being whatever number). I get the right page back.

It's only when they are combined that it does not work.

I've also tried making the parameter a variable and then passing it through but I get the same results. I also tried adding (`+1`) to the index, rather than calling `.next()` before it. Any ideas?

Comment: First thing - use `span.selected` instead of `span[class="selected"]`.

Comment: Oh yeah. i forgot about that, even though I'm using the regular one other places. Haha. It's been a long day.

Comment: Shouldn't one of the `<span>` elements start out with the "selected" class?

Comment: It does. I call `wizard.goTo(1);` first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7v8Xx/1/

You werent going far enough ahead in this line:

```
wizard.goTo($('#wizard-pages span[class="selected"]').next().index());
```

Add 1 to the index!!

```
wizard.goTo($('#wizard-pages span[class="selected"]').next().index()+1);
```

Comment: Was it really that simple? Gah. Thank you!

Comment: Just add 2 to the index. `.next()` is nothing but wasted CPU cycles.

Comment: In hindsight, I should have seen this as I was just calling index to go back one, so I should have needed to add two to go forward. Also thanks for the tip, Matt.